# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning how to default to the "latest" version

Tags: c#, .net-core, api-versioning

Other than changing startup.cs whenever a new version is built,

```
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
});
```

is there a way of specifying that the "default version" is the latest version, without specifying what that version is? e.g. some way of saying

```
config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersionLatest();
```

. . . or does this fly in the face of all that is considered holy by the RESTApi gods?

Thanks

Comment: Hah! Visiting my `ConfigureServices` and seeing that I'd forgotten to nudge the `DefaultApiVersion` to the next version makes this an interesting question for me. I'd probably just search the assembly with reflection for `ApiVersionAttribute` on `Controller` classes/actions and pick the highest, but perhaps there's a less brute-force approach. Maybe something with `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`, but we don't yet have a service-provider to get this from. Hmm...

Comment: How about this? https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Version-Selector#current-implementation-api-selector

Comment: @spender: That looks like the answer, why put it in a comment?

Comment: Cos I'm busy and i want you to try it first and report back!

Answer (score 2):

The *correct* answer depends a little bit about what you expect to achieve. The `DefaultApiVersion` only comes into play when no other API version is available. API versioning does **not** have a concept of *"no API version"*. API *version-neutral* means that an API accepts any and all API versions, including none at all. The *default* API version can also be thought of as the *initial* API version.

Here's a few scenarios where the `DefaultAPiVersion` comes into play:

- A controller has no attribution or conventions applied
- Selection of possible API versions yields no results

It *sounds* like you are interested in configuring the most current API version in a single place. You *can* use the `DefaultApiVersion` to do this, but only if the controller has no other attribution or conventions. If an API doesn't carry forward, you will have to explicitly decorate the controller with an attribute or convention that indicates the legacy API version to exclude it from the *latest* version. While this is possible, it's hard to follow IMO.

A better approach would probably to use an extension that that describes the behavior you want. For example:

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false )]
public sealed class LatestApiVersionAttribute : ApiVersionAttribute, IApiVersionProvider
{
  public LatestApiVersionAttribute() : base( new ApiVersion( 2, 0 ) ) { }
}
```

Now you can apply this to all your controllers a la:

```
[LatestApiVersion]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  // ommitted
}
```

This gives you the chance to manage the latest API version is single place. You might also consider using conventions so you don't even need the custom attribute. Attributes and conventions can be combined.

@spender does mention using a custom **IApiVersionSelector**; however, selection currently only comes into play when no API version has been specified. To enable this type of configuration, set things up as:

```
services.AddApiVersioning( options =>
{
   options.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector( options );
   options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
}
```

This will enable clients that do not specify an API version to always forward to the most recent version of the requested API. A client can still explicitly ask for a specific version, including the latest.

I hope that helps.